# Quartz.net firing previously scheduled jobs

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I just started using Quartz.net. I wrote a little routine to schedule multiple jobs. I am really not sure if I coded this properly. Hopefully there are some Quartz.NET experts that can help. I have three questions:

1. Does my trigger setup look correct? I would like to run a job everyday at 9AM and 3PM (I know you can't see the `market.LocalOpenTime` property but its always today's date at 9AM and the other object has 3PM.
2. I noticed when I run the program, it will always run the 9AM job (scheduled in the past). Anyway I can turn off this feature? I ran the program at 1PM. I assume if I run it at 4PM it will run these two past scheduled jobs.
3. How can I go about only running these jobs on weekdays?

   ```
   foreach (IJob job in GetJobsToSchedule())
   {
       i++;
       var market = (IMarket)job;

       IJobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl(market.JobName, null, market.GetType());           
       ITrigger trigger = new SimpleTriggerImpl(market.JobName, i.ToString(), market.LocalOpenTime, null, 1000, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));

       sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You might want to consider using a `CronTriggerImpl` with a schedule of `0 0 9,15 * * ?`. This will allow you to set your whole schedule with 1 trigger. Here is a good tutorial on cron triggers (even though it's for the previous Quartz version):
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_6.html

2) Set the `myCronTrigger.MisfireInstruction` property to DoNothing. The documentation says this value should be defined in the `CronTriggerImpl` class but I didn't see it. You may have better luck using IntelliSense in Visual Studio.

3) Check out the Cron tutorial link in (1) above. You could use something like this: `0 0 9,15 * * MON-FRI`

Comment: If you feel like this is your answer, please mark it as such. Thanks!